# Как считывать из файла поля структуры?

Tags: c

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h> 
#include<stdlib.h> 
#include <conio.h>

struct student
{
    char family_name[20];
    double age;
};

int average(struct student group[50], int answer, double mid)
{
    int i = 0, j, f;
    struct student sorted[50];
    for (j = 0; j < answer; j++)
    {
        if (group[j].age < mid)
        {
            sorted[i] = group[j];
            i++;
        }
    }
    struct student temp;
    for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
    {
        for (f = j; f < i; f++)
        {
            if (strcmp(sorted[f].family_name, sorted[j].family_name) > 0)
            {
                temp = sorted[f];
                sorted[f] = sorted[j];
                sorted[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    int k;
    for (k = 0; k < i; k++)
    {
        printf("%s\n", sorted[k].family_name);
        printf("%lf\n", sorted[k].age);
    }
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    double total = 0, mid = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int answer = 0;

    struct student group[50];

    //printf("HOW MUCH STUDENTS TO FIND: ");
    //scanf("%d",&answer);
    FILE *fi = NULL;

    fi = fopen("data.txt", "r");
    if (fi == NULL)
    {
        printf("error\n");
    }
    while(!feof(fi))
    { 
        fscanf(fi, "%s %lf", &group[i].family_name, &group[i].age);

        //printf("%s %lf\n",group[i].family_name, group[i].age);
        total += group[i].age;
        i++;

    } 
    fclose(fi);

    mid = total / i;
    printf("mid %lf", mid);
    average(group, i, mid);
    getchar();
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
fscanf(fi, "%s %lf", group[i].family_name, &group[i].age);
```

и надеяться, что впереди будет идти только одно слово, а не имя и фамилия :)